# Creating users with quickblox - session token generation

Tags: javascript, quickblox

I want to make a web-page that creates users.
To do that I have to generate a session token.
I looked up in the Quickblox's documentation and I found nothing about it.

Could anyone please guide me, step by step, how to generate a session token? (from signature-generation, to request, and finally obtaining the session token).

I might have skipped a step, if so, feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate QuickBlox token you should create session - make this query http://quickblox.com/developers/Authentication_and_Authorization#API_Session_Creation

For this query you need signature - read here how to generate signature http://quickblox.com/developers/Authentication_and_Authorization#Signature_generation

Also here is PHP example how to generate signature & obtain session token [How to generate QuickBlox authentication signature in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108986/how-to-generate-quickblox-authentication-signature-in-php) (last answer)