# Generate Session & QB-Token for Quickblox

Tags: php, chat, quickblox

I want to implement chat using `Quickblox` for my website. I need to create user dynamically. I am using following code it returns me signature but for next step to create new user I need token and I am not getting it.

```
$session_xml_data='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <response>
    <application_id>'.$application_id.'</application_id>
    <auth_key>'.$auth_key.'</auth_key>
    <timestamp>'.time().'</timestamp>
    <nonce>'.rand(111111,999999).'</nonce>
    <signature>'.$signature.'</signature>
</response>';
$session_xml_data = simplexml_load_string($session_xml_data);
$url ='https://api.quickblox.com/session.json';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml','QuickBlox-REST-API-Version: 0.1.0'));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$session_xml_data" );
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo '<br /> Token Here';print_r($result);
curl_close($ch);
echo '******** '.$token=$result;
```

Comment: Here is a right code to create a session via PHP

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108986/how-to-generate-quickblox-authentication-signature-in-php