# Quickblox - Unexpected error in application session (code 02)

Tags: php, rest, api, quickblox

I try to get quickblox token using [next code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108986/how-to-generate-quickblox-authentication-signature-in-php), and it works perfectly, but in same cases it fails with error:

```
{"errors":{"base":["Unexpected error in application session (code 02)"]}}
```

What does it mean?

I didn't find anything about it in official documentation...